# Error org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, spring, hsqldb

I try making Spring Embedded Database HSQL Exmple using JDBC but I get error,my code ,consol output and gist link are bellow.How to fix this project,thanks for helps.

[gist code](https://gist.github.com/fthsvk/4eb50ddca08f504f14db76f557597520)

```
 package com.fatih.model;

public class Calisan {
private String ad;
private String soyad;
public String getAd() {
    return ad;
}
public void setAd(String ad) {
    this.ad = ad;
}
public String getSoyad() {
    return soyad;
}
public void setSoyad(String soyad) {
    this.soyad = soyad;
}

public Calisan() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public Calisan(String ad, String soyad) {
    super();
    this.ad = ad;
    this.soyad = soyad;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Calisan [ad=" + ad + ", soyad=" + soyad + "]";
}




}
```

-

```
package com.fatih.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.fatih.model.Calisan;

public interface CalisanDAO {

public void calisanEkle(Calisan calisan);
public List<Calisan> caliasanListele();

    }
```

-

```
 package com.fatih.dao.impl;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import com.fatih.dao.CalisanDAO;
import com.fatih.model.Calisan;


@Named
public class CalisanDAOImpl implements CalisanDAO {


@Inject
private DataSource dataSource;







public CalisanDAOImpl() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}




public void calisanEkle(Calisan calisan) {
    PreparedStatement ps=null;
    Connection conn=null;

    try {

        conn=dataSource.getConnection();

        ps=conn.prepareStatement("insert into     Calisan(ad,soyad)values(?,?)");

        ps.setString(1, calisan.getAd());
        ps.setString(2, calisan.getSoyad());

        ps.executeUpdate();





    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try{
        if(ps!=null){
            ps.close();
        }
        }catch(SQLException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}

public List<Calisan> caliasanListele() {
    PreparedStatement ps=null;
    Connection conn=null;

    List<Calisan> calisanList=new ArrayList<Calisan>();

    try{

        conn=dataSource.getConnection();

        ps=conn.prepareStatement("select*from calisan");

        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){

            //int id=rs.getInt("calisanId");
            String ad=rs.getString("ad");
            String soyad=rs.getString("soyad");

            Calisan calisan=new Calisan(ad, soyad);

            calisanList.add(calisan);
        }
            System.out.println("Calisan listesi");

            for (Calisan calisan : calisanList) {
                System.out.println(calisan);
            }










    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return calisanList;
}

}
```

-

```
    package com.fatih.service;

import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import com.fatih.dao.impl.CalisanDAOImpl;
import com.fatih.model.Calisan;

@Named
public class CalisanService{




private CalisanDAOImpl calisanDAOImpl;







public CalisanService() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


@Inject
public CalisanService(CalisanDAOImpl calisanDAOImpl) {

    this.calisanDAOImpl = calisanDAOImpl;
}

public void calisanEkle(Calisan calisan){
    calisanDAOImpl.calisanEkle(calisan);
}

public List<Calisan> calisanListele(){
    return calisanDAOImpl.caliasanListele();
}

}
```

-

```
 package com.fatih.test;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.fatih.model.Calisan;
import com.fatih.service.CalisanService;

public class CalisanTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {

ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("app-    config.xml");

CalisanService calisanService=context.getBean(CalisanService.class);

Calisan calisan=new Calisan("ali" , "kaya"); 

calisanService.calisanEkle(calisan);


}
}
```

-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactoryBean">
    <property name="databasePopulator" ref="populator" />
    <property name="databaseType" value="HSQL" />
</bean>
<bean id="populator"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator">
    <property name="scripts">
        <list>
            <value>schema.sql</value>
            <value>data.sql</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>


<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.fatih" />
```

data.sql

```
insert into Calisan (ad, soyad) values ('Ayhan', 'Isik');

insert into Calisan ( ad, soyad) values ('Zeki', 'Müren');

insert into Calisan (ad, soyad) values ( 'Kemal','Sunal');
```

schema.sql

```
drop table Calisan if exists;

create table Calisan (ad varchar(50), soyad varchar(50));
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.fatih</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringDBJDBCEmbeddedDatabase</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


<properties>
    <spring.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>




    <dependency>

        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>

        <version>${spring.version}</version>

    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hsqldb/hsqldb -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
<artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
<version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>



</dependencies>








</project>
```

**Consol output**

> Eki 20, 2016 9:26:26 PM
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext
>   prepareRefresh INFO: Refreshing
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@31221be2:
>   startup date [Thu Oct 20 21:26:26 EEST 2016]; root of context
>   hierarchy Eki 20, 2016 9:26:26 PM
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader
>   loadBeanDefinitions INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path
>   resource [app-config.xml] Eki 20, 2016 9:26:27 PM
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
>    INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and
>   supported for autowiring Eki 20, 2016 9:26:27 PM
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext
>   refresh WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization -
>   cancelling refresh attempt
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
>   [app-config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
>     at com.fatih.test.CalisanTest.main(CalisanTest.java:12) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:606)
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:518)
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:504)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:241)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
>     ... 11 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   ... 43 more
>
> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
>   [app-config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
>     at com.fatih.test.CalisanTest.main(CalisanTest.java:12) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:606)
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:518)
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:504)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:241)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
>     ... 11 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   ... 43 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the spring-dao.jar.

`nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException`

Make sure you have the jar file in your classpath.

Comment: Thanks I added spring dao dependency project runned succesfully.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention that in your appconfig.xml (application context) you do not have defined any DataSource object. You defined a DataSourceFactory. That its not the same.

In your classes you are injecting a DataSource object.

So in your appconfig.xml (application context) you should replace this

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactoryBean">
    <property name="databasePopulator" ref="populator" />
    <property name="databaseType" value="HSQL" />
</bean>
<bean id="populator"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator">
    <property name="scripts">
        <list>
            <value>schema.sql</value>
            <value>data.sql</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

with this

```
<!-- jdbc:hsqldb:mem:dataSource -->
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema.sql" />
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:data.sql" />
    <!-- assuming you have your sql scripts in src/main/resources -->
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.